# Using <ul><li> instead of <select> for Navigation/Filtering

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm "modernizing" a website that currently uses `<select>` to allow the user to pick a "category" to display.  A contrived example:

```
<select>
    <option value="/Sales/1">Computers</option>
    <option value="/Sales/2">TVs</option>
    <option value="/Sales/3">Fidget Spinners</option>
</select>
```

Then of course javascript is used to navigate to the selected value.  And you can have a fallback `<submit>` button if javascript isn't enabled.

When the page is first loaded, the first item is selected by default (desired behavior).  After a postback, then the `<select>` can (does) display the currently selected `<option>` (also desired behavior).

I don't really have a problem with how this works.  It's perfectly usable and fits the bill.  The only downside I have is that you have little control over how the `<select>` is rendered in mobile browsers.  And then, there are the [HTML purists who insist that `<select>` shouldn't be used for navigation](https://baymard.com/blog/mobile-dropdown-navigation) (no offense).  *(At first I argued that I'm not using it for navigation, more as a filter, but the example image on that site shows someone selecting a category, which is more or less what I'm doing).*

So the ultimate questions here are:

1)  Should I continue to use `<select>`?  Or for the sake of "standards" and extra control over appearance, use a `<ul><li>` implementation?

2)  If I were to use `<ul><li>`, how do I make this work?  I can see how I can use CSS to show/hide the list items, but it seems like it would be a lot more complicated to replicate the behavior of showing the "selected" item when collapsed, and automatically being on the selected item when the list is shown.  Searched high and low, and couldn't find anything that does that.  Any examples or ideas?

PS  Might be worth noting that the options/items vary anywhere from about 10, up to 100 or so.  And, no, its not feasible (or desirable) to have a text box to specify or search for the option.

Comment: if it is just "linking" to another page then why not put an anchor in your li?

Comment: Technically, its not a different page, just supplying different route parameters to show the selected category.  But yes, if I were to go the <li> route then yes it would contain an <a>.  I got that part, but not sure how to mimic the behavior of a <select> in regards to displaying selected when collapsed and auto "scrolling" to selected when expanded.

Comment: if select is right for you, why dont you just style it with some lib like https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/ or any other ?

Comment: I guess no one seems to mind using a <select> for this scenario...  =)  I'm using purecss, but I had a look at your bootstrap example and I like it.  Didn't see anything similar for purecss after a quick search.  I'm still early in the design stages, so maybe I should consider using bootstrap instead...

Comment: Doesn't look like I'm going to get any more answers.  @DamianMartyniuk I was unaware that there were css/jquery libs out there that could override a mobile devices native `<select>` drop down behavior.  Why don't you post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style Your  with some library like: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/
you will keep all default  functionalities and have many more :)